# Dart: Type inference for class extensions on generic types

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to create a class extension on `Future` of a generic type to extract a value of a generic wrapper type.

```dart
abstract class GenericClass<T> {
  T foo();
}

class IntClass extends GenericClass<int> {
  @override
  int foo() => 42;
}

extension GenericClassExt<T> on Future<GenericClass<T>> {
  Future<T> resolve() => then((value) => value.foo());
}

Future<IntClass> produce() => Future.value(IntClass());

Future<void> main() async {
  final wrapper = produce();
  final val = wrapper.resolve();
  print('val: $val');
}
```

Here i would expect `val` to be inferred to be of type `int` (since produce() is a IntClass) and `wrapper` is correctly inferred as `Future<IntClass>`. But I see the following error:

> Missing variable type for 'val'.
>
> Try adding an explicit type like 'dynamic', or enable implicit-dynamic in your analysis options file.

The weird thing, on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/) the type seems to be inferred correctly (although it probably has implicit-dynamic enabled.. but it still seems to infer the variable type `int`):

[image: inferred in type]

Is there some way to refactor my class extension to correctly infer the type?

(tried with dart 2.9.0-18.0.dev and dart 2.8.4)

Comment: I think `Future<T> resolve() => then((value) => value.foo());` here the type inference is not able to determine what is `return type` of `resolve()`

Comment: I've tried your code locally and in the dartpad and everything is ok: it compiles and type is as you are expecting it.

Comment: @ChessMax Did you set `implicit-dynamic:false` locally in your `analysis_options.yaml`? https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#enabling-additional-type-checks

Comment: @herbert yes, also implicit-casts is false

Comment: @ChessMax thanks, seems like I've just hit a strange extension method behavior. The code was in lib/src/mylib.dart which is exported by lib/mylib.dart .. but for some reason lib/src/mylib.dart imported package:mylib/mylib.dart so the error message i saw in the IDE was not the original error. actually it thought the extension was defined twice `A member named 'resolve' is defined in extensions 'GenericClassExt' and 'GenericClassExt' and neither is more specific. `