# Dart failed type inference on generic extension

Tags: dart, generics, type-inference

Consider the following code:

```dart
class A<T> {
  T? t;
}

class B<T> extends A<T> {
  B({T? t}) {
    this.t = t;
  }
}

extension EA<T> on A<T> {
  B<T> toB() => B(this.t);
}

void main() {
  B<int> b1 = B(); // This infers correctly
  B<int> b2 = A().toB(); // Error: A value of type 'B<dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'B<int>'
}
```

A few other posts have been similar, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62574785) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71454239), but they don't seem quite the same, or resolved.  If Dart can resolve the type of `B()`, surely it ought to be able to resolve `A().toB()`?  Is this just a limitation of the type inference system?

Comment: Inferring `B()` to be `B<int>()` directly from the left-hand-side is pretty straightforward.  But inferring `A().toB()` to be `A<int>().toB()` is not: the type of `A` must already be statically known to determine which extension method to use, but the choice of the resolved extension method determines the exact type of `A`. "Surely it ought to be able to resolve `A().toB()`" seems like a gross overstatement. In general, you're better off using explicit types on the RHS and not using explicit types on the LHS.

Comment: Note that you don't even need a generic extension method: adding a `B<T> toB() => B(t: t);` method directly to `A<T>` wouldn't work either.  Inferring `A` backwards through the intermediate step of `toB()` is still a bridge too far.

Comment: @jamesdlin Ah, the point about "which extension" is valid.  Still seems like it COULD be inferred in many cases, but I'll grant it's less cut-and-dry.